# Vue Axios Put not saving in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, put

Wassup Guys,

I am writing a room session (scrum) in a single vue.

I implemented clickable divs (cards), that send the value of the chosen card to my DB in order to update the specific players estimation. The value is stored in a hidden input, which value I get through js so I can send this params in a put request to my controller.

I've binded the user's points in my model.

Initially loaded, it fetches everything with a get, it is dynamically updated after axios put (so no refresh needed) but not saved in my controller, altough I get a correct response.

My Card.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">ID: {{roomNumber}}</span>
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">Raumname: {{roomName}}</span>
    <span class="badge badge-warning">{{updatedAt}}</span>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" v-for="(user,index) in currentUsers" :key="index">
      <!-- Show Json Debug is User is Admin -->
      <div v-if="user.isAdmin == 1">
        <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">{{output}}</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Show User Attributes for each user in room -->
      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Spieler:{{user.name}}</div>

      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" v-if="user.isAdmin == 1">Rolle: Admin!</div>
      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" v-if="user.isAdmin !== 1">Rolle: No Admin!</div>

      <input
        type="number"
        class="alert alert-light"
        role="alert"
        v-model="userValue"
        placeholder="Points"
        disabled
      />
    </div>

    <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;" @click="sendData">
      <div class="card-header">7 Points</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">
          <input type="number" value="7" id="cardValue" hidden />
        </h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some explanation.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      output: "",
      roomNumber: "",
      roomName: "",
      currentUsers: "",
      userValue: "",
      playerComment: "Enter a reason...",
      updatedAt: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("/public/api/getPlayerInfo/" + this.$route.params.currentRoom)
      .then(response => {
        this.output = response.data;

        this.roomNumber = response.data.currentRoom.id;
        this.roomName = response.data.currentRoom.roomName;
        this.updatedAt = response.data.currentRoom.updated_at;

        this.currentUsers = response.data.currentUsers;
        this.userValue = response.data.currentUsers[1].pivot.userValue;

        console.log(this.currentUsers);
        console.log(this.userValue);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    sendData() {
      const updatedCardValue = document.getElementById("cardValue").value;
      axios
        .post("/public/values/" + this.$route.params.currentRoom, {
          _method: "PUT",
          cardValue: updatedCardValue
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.userValue = updatedCardValue
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },
    lastedit() {
      $updatedAt = updatedAt;
      var delta = Math.round((+new Date() - updatedAt) / 1000);

      var minute = 60,
        hour = minute * 60,
        day = hour * 24,
        week = day * 7;

      var fuzzy;

      if (delta < 30) {
        fuzzy = "just then.";
      } else if (delta < minute) {
        fuzzy = delta + " seconds ago.";
      } else if (delta < 2 * minute) {
        fuzzy = "a minute ago.";
      } else if (delta < hour) {
        fuzzy = Math.floor(delta / minute) + " minutes ago.";
      } else if (Math.floor(delta / hour) == 1) {
        fuzzy = "1 hour ago.";
      } else if (delta < day) {
        fuzzy = Math.floor(delta / hour) + " hours ago.";
      } else if (delta < day * 2) {
        fuzzy = "yesterday";
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

SessionUserController.php

```
  public function Values($roomid, Request $request)
    {
        // $updatedTimestamp = carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        $currentRoom = Session::findOrFail($roomid);
        // $timestamp = $currentRoom->updated_at->toDateTimeString();
        $currentUser = auth::user();

        $updatedValue = $request->cardValue;


        $currentUser->sessions()->update(['userValue' => $updatedValue]);
        return redirect()
        ->back()
        ->with('currentUser', $currentUser)
        ->with('currentRoom', $currentRoom);
```

web.php

```
Route::put('values/{id?}', 'SessionUserController@Values')
    ->name('sessions.values')
    ->middleware('auth');
```

[image]

Comment: This is a Laravel issue. It has nothing to do with Vue, therefore I would recommend you change the title

Comment: Check that the userValue property of Session is fillable

Comment: @AlecJoy I got not really a model, is is a n to n pivot table created by Laravel automatically.